# iOS 8 - Horizontal Scrolling Collection

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

What is the best way to go about building a one-row horizontal scrolling collection? I have seen this used in various apps, such as IMDB.

[image]

I have seen some implementations using table views with nested collection views, but is this possible to do using only a custom collection view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to go with a Collection View with horizontal flow for this specific row.
You can design the whole thing in your storyboard too.